# How do I tell if I am reviewing a question or an answer?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

I have recently earned the privilege which allows me to review suggested edits. I sometimes find it difficult to tell whether the edit is for a question or an answer and can see no obvious indication of what sort of post it is.

Is there something I'm missing or a trick to be able to quickly tell which sort of post it is?

Comment: This is a valid point, for particularly poor questions / answers I usually have a brief moment of "eh?"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look for **asked ## mins ago** (for questions) or **answered ## mins ago** (for answers) text towards the bottom of the post (above the user flair).

When an edit is suggested on a question:

> [image]

When an edit is suggested on an answer:

> [image]

Comment: Ah yes, conveniently hidden at the bottom of the post is faded text.

Comment: @DrYap There's a second indicator, but you really have to know to notice it. If it's a question, the question title will be blue, but if it's an answer it will be gray.